# Django - Keep track of comments

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a web app, where each product has its own "Profile". I need to add to the model some kind of field where i can add "Comments", with date and text, for keeping track of info such as change in formula, change of provider, change in price, etc.

Any ideas?

models.py

```
    from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Horse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nacimiento = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    nro = models.IntegerField()
    event = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s-%s' % (self.name, self.nro)
```

So for every event that happens, i need a new entrance with the description provided in the text field.

Comment: So you would like some kind of audit logs where you save the changes made to the model? Could you also post your product model?

Comment: @gdef_ i edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class HorseTracker(models.Model):
    horse = models.ForeignKey(Horse, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='horse')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

Each time you change something in your model you can create new instance of `HorseTracker` with description of changes you've made.

To make it more usefull you can use `TabularInline` in your `HorseAdmin`

```
class HorseTrackerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = HorseTracker

class HorseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'nacimiento', 'nro', 'event', 'slug', ]
    inlines = [ HorseTrackerInline, ]
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what i needed. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track various models I would suggest to use something like [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to keep track of the changes in your model.

Adding a `history` field to the model lets you save all the changes made to the fields and then access the history. If you want to add a custom message you can [add fields to the historical model](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/historical_model.html#adding-additional-fields-to-historical-models), and in a signal set the message.

```
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

class MessageHistoricalModel(models.Model):
    """
    Abstract model for history models tracking custom message.
    """
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Horse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    nro = models.IntegerField()
    event = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    history = HistoricalRecords(bases=[MessageHistoricalModel,])
```

Then using [signals](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html) you can get changes using [diff](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history_diffing.html) and then save a custom message stating the changes an who made them.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from simple_history.signals import (post_create_historical_record)

@receiver(post_create_historical_record)
def post_create_historical_record_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    history_instance = kwargs['history_instance'] # the historical record created

    # <use diff to get the changed fields and create the message>

    history_instance.message = "your custom message"
    history_instance.save()
```

You could generate a pretty generic signal that works for all your models tracked with a 'history' field.

Note: I renamed "nacimiento" as "birthdate" to keep consistency in naming all the fields in english.